# Pdf not being converted into JPEG image using pdf2image

Tags: python, pdf, pdf2image

I am using the following code to save pdf pages as images but its not storing as >JPEG but it is storing as >PPM file. How do I solve it?

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
pages = convert_from_path(path_to_pdf, output_folder=path_to_output, poppler_path=poppler_path)
for i in range(len(pages)):
    print(type(pages[i]))
    pages[i].save('page' + str(i) + '.jpg', 'JPEG')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what is happening...
With this line:

```py
pages = convert_from_path(path_to_pdf, output_folder=path_to_output, poppler_path=poppler_path)
```

You are actually doing 2 things:

1. writing `.ppm` files to the output folders, and
2. loading the `pages`, which are `PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile` objects.

The actual saving of the object to a JPEG is made after, with

```py
pages[i].save('page' + str(i) + '.jpg', 'JPEG')
```

This means that to obtain the result you want to obtain, you just have to avoid providing the `output_folder` in the `convert_from_path` function and provide it while saving instead, as such:

```py
import os
from pdf2image import convert_from_path

pages = convert_from_path(path_to_pdf, poppler_path=poppler_path)
for i in range(len(pages)):
    print(type(pages[i]))
    pages[i].save(os.path.join(path_to_output, 'page' + str(i) + '.jpg'), format='JPEG')
```